# How to optimally spread draws when calculating multiple expectations

Tags: optimization, conditional-probability, simulation, expected-value, monte-carlo

Suppose we want to calculate some expectation:

$$E_YE_{X|Y}[f(X,Y)]$$

Suppose we want to approximate this using Monte Carlo simulation.

$$E_YE_{X|Y}[f(X,Y)] \approx \frac1{RS}\sum_{r=1}^R\sum_{s=1}^Sf(x^{r,s},y^r)$$

BUT suppose it is costly to draw samples from both distributions, so that we only can afford to draw a fixed number $K$.

How should we allocate $K$?  Examples include $K/2$ draws to each distribution, or in the extreme, one draw in the outer and $K-1$ draws in the inner, vice versa etc.....

My intuition tells me that it will have to do with the variance/entropy of the distributions relative to each other.  Suppose the outer one is a mass point, then the division of $K$ that minimizes MC error would be draw 1 of the $Y$ and draw $K-1$ of the $X|Y$.

Hopefully this was clear.

Comment: Fixed it for you

Comment: The "vice versa" and your comment to @Xi'ans answer seem to indicate that you consider it possible to draw the outer variable more times than the inner variable, but how could that make sense -- aren't all outers for which $0$ inners are drawn wasted?

Comment: Fair enough, minimum one draw per outer I guess.  Or you could think of programming it to save the draw I suppose

Comment: @robertevansanders Please confirm whether the interpretation of your question in the first two sentences of Xi'ans answer is correct

Comment: Like you said, yeah, but switch y and x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This is a very interesting question with little documentation in the
>   Monte Carlo literature, except in connection with *stratification* and
>   *Rao-Blackwellisation*. This is possibly due to the fact that the computations of the expected conditional variance and of the variance
>   of the conditional expectation are rarely feasible.

First, let us assume you run $R$ simulations from $\pi_X$, $x_1,\ldots,x_R$ and for each simulated $x_r$, you run $S$ simulations from $\pi_{Y|X=x_r}$, $y_{1r},\ldots,y_{sr}$. Your Monte Carlo estimate is then
$$\delta(R,S)=\frac{1}{RS}\sum_{r=1}^R\sum_{s=1}^S f(x_r,y_{rs})$$
The variance of this estimate is decomposed as follows
\begin{align*}
\text{var} \{\delta(R,S)\} &= \frac{1}{R^2S^2} R\text{var} \left\{\sum_{s=1}^S f(x_r,y_{rs})\right\}\\
&= \frac{1}{RS^2} \text{var}_X\mathbb{E}_{Y|X}\left\{\sum_{s=1}^S f(x_r,y_{rs})\big|x_r\right\}+\frac{1}{RS^2}\mathbb{E}_{X}\text{var}_{Y|X}
\left\{\sum_{s=1}^S f(x_r,y_{rs})\big|x_r\right\}\\
&=\frac{1}{RS^2} \text{var}_X\{ S \mathbb{E}_{Y|X}[f(x_r,Y)|x_r]\}+
\frac{1}{RS^2} \mathbb{E}_{X}[S\text{var}_{Y|X}\{f(x_r,Y)|x_r\}]\\
&=\frac{1}{R} \text{var}_X\{\mathbb{E}_{Y|X}[f(x_r,Y)|x_r]\}+
\frac{1}{RS} \mathbb{E}_{X}[\text{var}_{Y|X}\{f(x_r,Y)|x_r\}]\\
&\stackrel{K=RS}{=}\frac{1}{R}\text{var}_X\{\mathbb{E}_{Y|X}[f(x_r,Y)|x_r]\}+
\frac{1}{K} \mathbb{E}_{X}[\text{var}_{Y|X}\{f(x_r,Y)|x_r\}]
\end{align*}
Therefore if one wants to minimise this variance the optimal choice is $R=K$. Implying that $S=1$. Except when the first variance term is null, in which case it does not matter. However, as discussed in the comments, the assumption $K=RS$ is unrealistic as it does not account for the production of one $x_r$ [or assumes this comes for free].

Now let us assume different simulation costs and the budget constraint $R+aRS=b$, meaning that the $y_{rs}$'s cost $a$ times more to simulate than the $x_r$'s. The above decomposition of the variance is then
$$\frac{1}{R}\text{var}_X\{\mathbb{E}_{Y|X}[f(x_r,Y)|x_r]\}+
\frac{1}{R(b-R)/aR} \mathbb{E}_{X}[\text{var}_{Y|X}\{f(x_r,Y)|x_r\}]$$
which can be minimised in $R$ as
$$R^*=b\big/1+\{a\mathbb{E}_{X}[\text{var}_{Y|X}\{f(x_r,Y)|x_r\}/\text{var}_X\{\mathbb{E}_{Y|X}[f(x_r,Y)|x_r]\}\}^{1/2}$$
[the closest integer under the constraints $R\ge 1$ and $S\ge 1$],
except when the first variance is equal to zero, in which case $R=1$. When $\mathbb{E}_{X}[\text{var}_{Y|X}\{f(x_r,Y)|x_r\}]=0$, the minimum variance corresponds to a maximum $R$, which leads to $S=1$ in the current formalism.

Note also that this solution should be compared with the symmetric solution when the inner integral is in $X$ given $Y$ and the outer integral is against the marginal in $Y$ (assuming the simulations are also feasible in this order).

> *An interesting extension to the question would be to consider a different number of simulations $S(x_r)$ for each simulated $x_r$,
>   depending on the value $\text{var}_{Y|X}\{f(x_r,Y)|x_r\}$.*

Comment: In the final conclusion, you seem to be assuming $K=RS$ but in the setting of the question $K=RS+R$ since draws of the outer variable are supposed to be counted, too. The result here says that if sampling the outer variable was free, of course one should sample a new outer for every inner. (Also, the role of $x$ and $y$ are switched here compared to the question but that of course does not matter).

Comment: Yes but we can decide the value of $R$... Consider the degenerate setting where the outer var $X$ is a.s. constant. It's better to sample the constant once and $Y$ $K-1$ times, rather than the constant $K/2$ times and $Y$ $K/2$ times (which is what $S=1$ would imply)? Or am I completely misunderstanding the question? (I only now read the second sentence of your comment -- isn't the assumption stated in the question that they have the same cost)

Comment: @Xi'an yes Kolkata is correct, your solution cannot generally hold.   Suppose now that the inner variable has a degenerate distribution and the outer has meaningful variance, then you'd want to sample as few inner draws as possible

Comment: I think your answer can't be right. Suppose the inside distribution is degenerate and the outside is large variance, how can S be 1

Comment: @robertevansanders: if the inner distribution is degenerate, $\text{var}_{Y|X}\{f(x_r,Y)|x_r\}=0$, hence $R^*=b$ and we pick the closest integer $R$ under the constraints $S\ge 1$ and $R(1+aS)\le b$, which means taking $S=1$ to make $R$ as close as possible to $b$.

Comment: Forget the constraints for a second, just think logically in the case where you have just a fixed number of draws.   It does not make sense that as a rule you'd only want to draw ONE of the outer distribution.   Again the counter to this is that suppose the X|Y is degenerate and Y is Poisson(lambda).   Or, suppose Y is degenerate and X|Y is Poisson(lambda).  You'd never be able to resort to such a heuristic generally, and that's what your solution seems to suggest

Comment: Ok my bad, let me take a closer look.  So in my situation, you're saying that you would want to draw only 1 inner draw for each outer draw to minimize the MC error?

Comment: To answer your #1 question, I wonder if you read my entire answer: the $R^*$ that I obtain gives the optimal number of outer simulations, from which the inner number can be derived as $S^*=(b-R^*)/aR^*$. Up to rounding. To answer the #2 question, a practical implementation of the optimisation would have to be devised, which is not clear to me despite thinking about it in the past two days.